# unhandled exception: IOException must be caught or thrown

Tags: java, netbeans, exception

So recently I have started work on my own IRC client/server in Java. NetBeans is saying that I have an unhandled IOException. However, looking at my code I do a try-catch block that catches the IOException. Here is my code:

```
package some.package.name;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class IRCServer extends ServerSocket {

    private ServerSocket server;
    private int port;

    /**
     * <p>Main constructor. Provides default port of 6667</p>
     */
    public IRCServer() {
        this(6667);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Secondary constructor. Uses port defined by either user or Main constructor</p>
     *
     * @param port The port to listen to for the server
     */
    public IRCServer(int port) { //This is where NetBeans show the error
        this.port = port;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException caught\n" + e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>Overrides parent String toString()</p>
     *
     * @return PORT the server is listening to
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PORT: " + this.port;
    }
}
```

Note that the `IOException` in the `try...catch` is, indeed, `java.io.IOExecption`.

What is causing the compilation error?

EDIT: I have tried the same code in both Eclipse and by compiling it via cmd. It is still giving the same error

Comment: Try to restart your IDE

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you sure you're catching `java.io.IOException`?

Comment: Is this all the code? Are you sure that's the line that NetBeans marks?

Comment: @nogard Yes, I have restarted the IDE and the problem still persists

Comment: @starf Yes, I am sure that `java.io.IOException` is being caught

Comment: @RealSkeptic no, this is not all the code, just the constructor that was erroring. the full code is here: [link](http://pastebin.com/dHnMReX6)

Comment: Your problem is, that you extend ServerSocket. This has a default constructor of [`ServerSocket() throws IOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket--) which is implicitely called since you left out the `super()`. I think simply removing the extends is best here. Use composition instead of inheritance. Unfortunatelly you cant add super() after the try. Voting to reopen it, it is perfectly fine and a good problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your class both extends `ServerSocket` and has a `ServerSocket` field. This means that for every instance of `IRCServer` you theoretically have *two* `ServerSocket` instances. One is the `IRCServer` itself, because it extends it, and one is the embedded `ServerSocket` you named `server`.

This in itself is a serious design problem - there is no need to extend a class if you are not actually relying on its original functionality in any way. And if you intended to use the `IRCServer` as a `ServerSocket`, you shouldn't have an additional one embedded in. `this` becomes your `server`.

But the issue that causes the compilation error is the fact that every constructor implicitly or explicitly calls the `super()` constructor. If the original class had a no-args constructor - and it does - then if you fail to call `super(...)` yourself, it will be done for you.

However, the constructors of `ServerSocket` are declared as:

```
public ServerSocket() throws IOException
```

and

```
public ServerSocket(int port) throws IOException
```

This means that the implicit call to the `super()` constructor happens right *before* your `try...catch`, and it throws a checked exception. It means that you have to declare your own constructor as `throws IOException`, as there is no way to surround a `super()` call with `try...catch`.

My advice would be either to extend the class properly or delegate without extending. Properly extending means no `server` variable. And your constructors would look like:

```
/**
 * <p>Main constructor. Provides default port of 6667</p>
 */
public IRCServer() throws IOException {
    this(6667);
}

/**
 * <p>Secondary constructor. Uses port defined by either user or Main constructor</p>
 *
 * @param port The port to listen to for the server
 */
public IRCServer(int port) throws IOException {
    super(port);
    this.port = port;
}
```

And properly delegating would mean keeping most of your original code but removing the `extends ServerSocket`, and then you will not be able to use `IRCServer` polymorphically as a `ServerSocket`.